# Why is equals() method not working as intended?

Tags: java, equals

This is my current implementation of equals which compares if two matrix are the same. The problem is that when I run the test it says they are different.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj) return true;
    if(obj == null) return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Matrix)) return false;

    Matrix matrix = (Matrix) obj;
    int counter = 0;
    if(this.rowIndex == matrix.rowIndex && this.columnIndex == matrix.columnIndex){

        for(int i=0; i<this.rowIndex; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<this.columnIndex; j++)
                if(this.matrix[i][j] == matrix.matrix[i][j]);
                    counter++;
    }
    return counter == (matrix.rowIndex * matrix.columnIndex);
}
```

```
@Test
void changeValorTest(){
    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(3, 3, true);
    matrix1.changeValor(1,1,5);
    Integer[][] matrix2Real = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(matrix2Real, true);
    assertEquals(matrix1.matrix, matrix2.matrix);

    assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> matrix1.changeValor(0,-10, 7));
}
```

And the output:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@305fd85d<[[0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0]]> but was: [[Ljava.lang.Integer;@7a1ebcd8<[[0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0]]>

Expected :[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@305fd85d
Actual   :[[Ljava.lang.Integer;@7a1ebcd8
```

I have equals in the Matrix class. Is it because of its implementation or am I doing anything else wrong?

Comment: You are comparing the internal arrays instead of the `Matrix` instances: `assertEquals(matrix1, matrix2);`

Comment: If I do that it says org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :e2.Matrix@305fd85d
Actual   :e2.Matrix@458c1321

Comment: I had to change the equals as Louis Wasserman said and change what you told me to. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(this.matrix[i][j] == matrix.matrix[i][j]);
```

Delete the semicolon at the end of this line.

With the semicolon there, your code is equivalent to

```
if(this.rowIndex == matrix.rowIndex && this.columnIndex == matrix.columnIndex){
    for(int i=0; i<this.rowIndex; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<this.columnIndex; j++) {
            if(this.matrix[i][j] == matrix.matrix[i][j]) {
            }
        }
    }
    counter++;
}
```

...which does not do what you want it to.

(This is an excellent reason to use an autoformatter, which will show you the misleading indentation.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(this.matrix[i][j] == matrix.matrix[i][j])
                counter++;
```

Just guessing here since I cannot see the rest of the object, but you are comparing if the object contained in i,j position in both Matrix are the same. You need to compare their value.

On the other hand, you are comparing the internal matrix field of Matrix class, but you seem to be overriding equals just for the Matrix class. try changing

```
assertEquals(matrix1.matrix, matrix2.matrix);
```

to

```
assertEquals(matrix1, matrix2);
```

Comment: As I said to fps, if I do that i get org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :e2.Matrix@305fd85d
Actual   :e2.Matrix@458c1321      Maybe it is because each matrix is made with different constructors, but in the end they should have the same parameters

Comment: Doing what you said and quiting the ; of the if in equals it works. Thank you!